# Como salvar no banco de dados o mesmo objeto usando entityFramework .net MVC?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, mvc

Preciso fazer um update em uma tabela no banco de dados usando entityFramework,
pois quando atualizo um valor de um campo e mando salvar ,dá erro.

Por favor alguem tem uma forma de resolver isso??

grato

```
   usuarioVM.ContatoUsuarios = ContatoUsuarioRepositorio.ObterContatoSemUsuario();

   //obtenho os meus usuarios que eu quero fazer o update         

foreach (var item in usuarioVM.ContatoUsuarios) //Lista dos meus objetos
        {
            var contatoUsuario = new ContatoUsuario() 
            {
                //Codigo=item.Codigo,
                CodigoUsuario = usuario.CodUsuario,
                Codigo=item.Codigo,//Adicionando os novos valores para as minhas propriedades do novo objeto
                CodTipoContato=item.CodTipoContato,
                Descricao=item.Descricao             
            };

            ContatoUsuarioRepositorio.Adicionar(contatoUsuario);//metodo do meu repositorio onde adiciono o objeto 
            ContatoUsuarioRepositorio.Commit();  //  metodo do meu repositorio "this.Context.SaveChanges();"          
        }


        public void Commit()
      {
         this.Context.SaveChanges();//Metodos utilizidados em outra classe mostrei aqui soh pra ter uma nocao
      }
        public void Adicionar(ContatoUsuario contato)
      {
        this.Context.ContatoUsuarios.Add(contato);
       }
```

Comment: Olá, qual erro que da quando você tenta salvar?

Comment: Não são permitidas novas transações porque há outros threads em execução na sessão

Comment: Poderia por favor postar parte de código para que possamos analisar?

Comment: E também a exceção lançada.

Answer (score 5):

Não há necessidade dos métodos `Commit` e `Adicionar`.

Retire também o `SaveChanges` de dentro do laço.

Use simplesmente:

```
usuarioVM.ContatoUsuarios = ContatoUsuarioRepositorio.ObterContatoSemUsuario();

//obtenho os meus usuarios que eu quero fazer o update         

foreach (var item in usuarioVM.ContatoUsuarios) //Lista dos meus objetos
{
    var contatoUsuario = new ContatoUsuario() 
    {
        CodigoUsuario = usuario.CodUsuario,
        Codigo = item.Codigo,//Adicionando os novos valores para as minhas propriedades do novo objeto
        CodTipoContato = item.CodTipoContato,
        Descricao = item.Descricao             
    };

    Context.ContatoUsuarios.Add(contato);      
}

Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Show problema resolvido

Comment: @HansMiller Quando uma resposta resolver o seu problema, marque-a como aceita... você não aceitou resposta de nenhuma das questões que fez, e nem ao menos votou em qualquer uma delas. Assim, as pessoas vão parar de responder suas questões, afinal o estimulo que elas possuem (além do grande nível de altruísmo dessas almas ajudantes) após dar uma resposta correta e bem feita, é ver que ela foi aceita, e ganhar alguma reputação por isso. Por favor... leia o link *[Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079)*